# SQL code: adding value to one code but shown in other code as well

Tags: mysql, sql

could somebody help me with this, please? I was checking answers around the net but still not successful.
I have two codes, code #1:

```
SELECT subject_note,ticket_id,created_time,status,
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(datacenter,1,3)) region
FROM sort_ticket WHERE ticket_type = 1 AND status =0 AND team_type = 1 AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(closed_date)) = MONTH(NOW())
 and YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(closed_date)) = YEAR(NOW())
AND 
(
-- ASH
owner_id = 812400897 
or owner_id = 1392249056 
or owner_id = 739243661 
or owner_id = 100002941128738 
or owner_id = 619251675 
or owner_id = 502392893 
)
```

and code #2:

```
SELECT
  subject_note, 
  cyborg_verify_tries,
    ticket_id,
    closed_date,
    created_time,
    status,
UPPER(SUBSTRING(datacenter,1,3)) region
FROM sort_ticket
WHERE ticket_type = 1
     AND status =0
     AND team_type = 1
  and (FROM_UNIXTIME(closed_date)) >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND
(
-- ASH
owner_id = 812400897 
or owner_id = 1392249056
or owner_id = 739243661
or owner_id = 100002941128738 
or owner_id = 619251675 
or owner_id = 502392893 
)
```

Both of these codes creating table and giving me the results what is good.
Problem what I have in here is I have to add manually every NEW "owner_id" into each code.

Is there any way how I could add NEW "owner_id" only into any code and second would be updated automatically? Both info are taken from the same table "sort_ticket".

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra table, where you put in the user id's and replace the fixed values with a select on this data:

```
SELECT
  subject_note, 
  cyborg_verify_tries,
    ticket_id,
    closed_date,
    created_time,
    status,
UPPER(SUBSTRING(datacenter,1,3)) region
FROM sort_ticket
WHERE ticket_type = 1
     AND status =0
     AND team_type = 1
  and (FROM_UNIXTIME(closed_date)) >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND
(
-- ASH
select owner_id from newtable
)
```

same in the other select

Comment: `CREATE TABLE newtable(
   owner_id int primary key not null )`
and make a inner join between sort_ticket and this newtable, where sort_ticket.owner_id = newtable.owner_id

Now you just have to add owners to this new table

Comment: Hi Foo Bar, thank you for the the tip, this is what I was exactly thinking about and it is the simplest solution but problem is I can not create new table as I do not have access to the Database, I can only create SQL Code to get the values. Is there any other option, like create function or trigger what I could use in code#2 to not manually update 'owner_id' on code#2?

Comment: @morzi39 No you can not do it.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank you for the update and info. :( I thought so but was hoping there could be some other way :(

Comment: @morzi39 The only way i see is the suggest way with a new table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional table or an additonal view. Use a join to the new table/view in your queries and add new owner_id with an insert in the table or an UNION in the view.
To solve your proble with a view you can do this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_sort_ticket_owner AS
SELECT 812400897 as owner_id
UNION
SELECT 1392249056 as owner_id
UNION
SELECT 739243661 as owner_id
UNION
SELECT 100002941128738 as owner_id
UNION
SELECT 619251675 as owner_id
UNION
SELECT 502392893 as owner_id
--UNION
--SELECT newnumber as ownder_id

SELECT subject_note,ticket_id,created_time,status,
UPPER(SUBSTRING(datacenter,1,3)) region
FROM sort_ticket st
JOIN v_sort_ticket_owner sto
ON st.owner_id = sto.owner_id
WHERE st.ticket_type = 1 AND st.status =0 AND st.team_type = 1 AND
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.closed_date)) = MONTH(NOW())
and YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.closed_date)) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you, just little question - can I use "v_sort_ticket_owner" on code#2 without creating VIEW on code#2?

Comment: once you created the VIEW you can use it in code#1 as well as in code#2

Comment: ok, thx again, but as I mentioned to Foo Bar I do not think it will allow me to create table but never tried VIEW, I'll try it and let you know.